# arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True not working for Merge of ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, merge, overwriteoutput

```
AOI_test = "AOI_test.shp"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

for i in loc_list:
    AOI = "AOI_" + i + ".shp"
    arcpy.Select_analysis("locality", AOI, " \"LOCALITY\" = '%s'" % (i))
    arcpy.Merge_management([AOI_test, AOI], AOI_test)
```

This code isn't working for some reason.

Have I understood this code incorrectly, or should I be able to overwrite the merge output FC (AOI_test)  repeatedly, now that I have specified that this is acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding is with how [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) works, which is (with my bolding and italicizing), that it:

> Combines multiple input datasets of the same data type into a single,
>   ***new*** output dataset.

Let's assume that your loc_list is `["A","B"]`, then the first time Merge runs in your script the syntax used evaluates to:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(["AOI_test.shp", "AOI_A.shp"], "AOI_test.shp")
```

Your output dataset is NOT new, it is the same as one of your two inputs.

---

In response to our discussion as comments I have included the untested code below to illustrate how I am suggesting that you could perform a single Merge.  As far as I can see there is no documented limit to the number of feature classes that can be merged together, but it will be interesting to see if 600 is too many.  I would first test  with 3 feature classes to make sure the code works first then see if any limitation is encountered when you retest with all 600*.

```
AOI_test = "AOI_test.shp"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
aoiList = []

for i in loc_list:
    AOI = "AOI_" + i + ".shp"
    aoiList.append(AOI)
    arcpy.Select_analysis("locality", AOI, " \"LOCALITY\" = '%s'" % (i))

arcpy.Merge_management(aoiList, AOI_test)
```